# ConcurrentModificationException in iterator.next() I cannot find another solution

Tags: java, exception, concurrentmodification

I'm currently coding a little net thing and wanted to cicle threw all of my players so I used ArrayLists and Lists but there were alot of Exception so going deep to the problem I replaced them with Iterators but I'm getting Concurrent modification exceptions in all the "it.next()" :/.
So if please you can help me understand the problem :).

```
    @Override
public void run()
{
    StringBuilder l = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<UUID> pc;
    Iterator<Packet> pa;
    while (Jelly.isSTATUS()) {
        pc = Jelly.getOnlinePlayers().keySet().iterator();
        while (pc.hasNext())
            try {
                System.out.println("ENTERED!");
                Player p = Jelly.getOnlinePlayers().get(pc.next());
                System.out.println(p.getIGN());
                if (Packetsts.containsKey(p) && !Packetsts.get(p).isEmpty())
                    try {
                        pa = Packetsts.get(p).iterator();
                        while(pa.hasNext()) {
                            Packet i = pa.next();
                            for ( String j : i.getData())
                                l.append(j + ",");
                            l.append("es");

                            System.out.println("Data: " + l.toString());
                            byte[] toSendBytes = l.toString().getBytes();
                            int toSendLen = toSendBytes.length;
                            byte[] toSendLenBytes = new byte[4];
                            toSendLenBytes[0] = (byte)(toSendLen & 0xff);
                            toSendLenBytes[1] = (byte)(toSendLen >> 8 & 0xff);
                            toSendLenBytes[2] = (byte)(toSendLen >> 16 & 0xff);
                            toSendLenBytes[3] = (byte)(toSendLen >> 24 & 0xff);
                            PrintStreams.get(p).write(toSendLenBytes);
                            PrintStreams.get(p).write(toSendBytes);

                            Packetsts.get(p).remove(i);
                            l.setLength(0);
                        }
                    } catch ( Exception ex) { }
            } catch (ConcurrentModificationException ex){ ex.printStackTrace(); }
    }
    System.out.println("END!");
}
```

Thank you :)

UPDATE:

```
    @Override
public void run()
{
    StringBuilder l = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<UUID> pc = Jelly.getOnlinePlayers().keySet().iterator();
    Iterator<Packet> pa;
    while (Jelly.isSTATUS())
        if (!Jelly.getOnlinePlayers().keySet().isEmpty()) {
            pc = Jelly.getOnlinePlayers().keySet().iterator();
            while (pc.hasNext()) {
                UUID u = pc.next();
                Player p = Jelly.getOnlinePlayers().get(u);
                if (Packetsts.containsKey(p) && !Packetsts.get(p).isEmpty())
                    try {
                        pa = Packetsts.get(p).iterator();
                        while(pa.hasNext()) {
                            Packet i = pa.next();
                            for ( String j : i.getData())
                                l.append(j + ",");
                            l.append("es");

                            System.out.println("Data: " + l.toString());
                            byte[] toSendBytes = l.toString().getBytes();
                            int toSendLen = toSendBytes.length;
                            byte[] toSendLenBytes = new byte[4];
                            toSendLenBytes[0] = (byte)(toSendLen & 0xff);
                            toSendLenBytes[1] = (byte)(toSendLen >> 8 & 0xff);
                            toSendLenBytes[2] = (byte)(toSendLen >> 16 & 0xff);
                            toSendLenBytes[3] = (byte)(toSendLen >> 24 & 0xff);
                            PrintStreams.get(p).write(toSendLenBytes);
                            PrintStreams.get(p).write(toSendBytes);

                            l = new StringBuilder();
                        }
                        Packetsts.get(p).clear();
                    } catch ( Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        }
    System.out.println("END!");
}
```

Line "UUID u = pc.next();" please, I really hate concurrent modification exception :/

Comment: If you want to modify a collection while iterating through that collection, the modification must be done by calling one of the iterator's methods. So what's wrong is Packetsts.get(p).remove(i). The removal must be done by calling iterator.remove().

Comment: what is your end goal? after you remove all the packets?

Comment: Also, please stop catching ConcurrentModiciationException and Exception. Those exceptions should not be caught. Especially if you ignore them.

Comment: So. Should I replace it with "pa.remove()"?

Comment: let me guess, the error is at Packetsts.get(p).clear();

Comment: No. That line is working fine.

Comment: My goal after removing all that packets is checking for new packets so I only have this class checking for that and sending them.

Comment: so you have a bunch of packets and you have a bunch of new packets. now you only want to keep the new packets and remove all the rest? is that so?

Comment: Yes, if they are sent they should be removed but the new packets need to be sent then removed

Comment: Never ever do this, not even for a temporary test!  "catch ( Exception ex) { }"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not allowed

```
Packetsts.get(p).remove(i);
```

as you are simultaneously iterating over the ArrayList which you are trying to modify. How about making a copy of it when the loop begins? What is your end goal after removing the elements?

Comment: So. Should I replace it with "pa.remove()"?

Comment: umm, no. it would be best to create a new List at the beginning of the loop

Comment: @CavariuX For me `pa.remove()` sounds reasonable but the iterator must not necessarily implement that method and may throw an UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: Well, I managed to fix it but now the error is striking another line :/
Check update please

Comment: a bit more clarification on why you are removing the elements would help. i would still recommend creating a new list. and once all the elements are removed, do you need to return the list?

Comment: Well, I am not returning anything but I really need to modify that list beacause from that depends also other classes.

Comment: Actually it works fine 2-3 times and then it crashes